# Solving a system of equations for a fraction

Tags: equation-solving, system, system-variables

I want to solve a system of equations not for one specific variable but for a fraction of two variables. How can I do that?

I want to solve:

```
(V2-V1)/R1+V2*s*C1+(V2-V3)*s*C2+(V2-V5)/Rf==0
(V3-V2)*s*C2+V3/R2==0
V4/Ra+(V4-V5)/Rb==0
V3-V4==0
```

For $V5/V1$

Comment: Take a look at `Solve` in the documentation, and if you still are stuck, come back and tell us where...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I did, and I can only solve for one specific variabe instead of a fraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single expression by specifying four variables to solve:

```
V5/V1 /. Solve[sys, {V5, V1, V3, V2}][[1]]
```

> (C2 R2 (Ra + Rb) Rf s)/(
>   R1 Ra + Ra Rf - C2 R1 R2 Rb s + C1 R1 Ra Rf s + C2 R1 Ra Rf s + 
>    C2 R2 Ra Rf s + C1 C2 R1 R2 Ra Rf s^2)

Note however you approach this problem you will get different results depending on which other two symbols you decide to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

This is looking for:

Elimination for variable `V2`:

```
 eq = {(V2 - V1)/R1 + V2*s*C1 + (V2 - V3)*s*C2 + (V2 - V5)/Rf == 
 0, (V3 - V2)*s*C2 + V3/R2 == 0, V4/Ra + (V4 - V5)/Rb == 0, 
 V3 - V4 == 0};
 s1 = Eliminate[eq, V2]
```

Elimination for variable `V4`:

```
 s2 = Eliminate[{s1[[1]], s1[[2]], s1[[3]]}, V4]
```

Solve for: `{V5,V1}`:

```
 sol = Solve[{s2[[1]], s2[[2]]}, {V1, V5}]
```

Fraction of `V5/V1`:

```
 (V5 /. sol[[1]])/(V1 /. sol[[1]]) // FullSimplify
```

> $\frac{\text{V5}}{\text{V1}}=\frac{\text{C2} \text{R2} (\text{Ra}+\text{Rb}) \text{Rf} s}{-\text{C2} \text{R1} \text{R2}
>    \text{Rb} s+\text{Ra} \text{Rf} (1+\text{C2} \text{R2} s)+\text{R1} \text{Ra} (1+\text{Rf} s
>    (\text{C1}+\text{C2}+\text{C1} \text{C2} \text{R2} s))}$

**EDITED:**

One line of code:

```
eq = {(V2 - V1)/R1 + V2*s*C1 + (V2 - V3)*s*C2 + (V2 - V5)/Rf == 
0, (V3 - V2)*s*C2 + V3/R2 == 0, V4/Ra + (V4 - V5)/Rb == 0, 
V3 - V4 == 0};
s1 = Eliminate[eq, V2];
s2 = Eliminate[{s1[[1]], s1[[2]], s1[[3]]}, V4];
sol = Solve[{s2[[1]], s2[[2]]}, {V1, V5}];
frac = (V5 /. sol[[1]])/(V1 /. sol[[1]]) // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to do this in one line of code instead for a few lines?

Answer (score 1):

To solve for arbitrary groupings of values, I usually introduce dummy variables and eliminate.

```
sys = {(V2 - V1)/R1 + V2*s*C1 + (V2 - V3)*s*C2 + (V2 - V5)/Rf == 0,
   (V3 - V2)*s*C2 + V3/R2 == 0,
   V4/Ra + (V4 - V5)/Rb == 0,
   V3 - V4 == 0,
   χ == V5/V1};
Solve[sys, {χ}, {V1, V2, V3, V4, V5}]
```

In this case, `χ` is defined equivalent to what we're looking for, so we solve for it while eliminating all of the `V` variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  in this way.

```
V5/V1 /. Solve[eq, {V1, V5}, {V2, V3, V4}]
```